# Are measures uniquely characterized by integrals against $\frac{1-x^\lambda}{1-x}$, $\lambda>0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a Radon measure on $[0,1]$. Does
$$
\int_{[0,1]} \frac{1-x^{\lambda}}{1-x}\mu(dx)=0 \quad\forall \lambda>0
$$
imply $\mu\equiv 0$? (With $\frac{1-x^{\lambda}}{1-x}:=\lambda$ for $x=1$.)

EDIT: After some thought, I realized that, by the Hahn-Banach theorem, I may equivalently ask whether the span of $\{\frac{1-x^{\lambda}}{1-x}: \lambda>0\}$ is dense in $(C([0,1]),\|\cdot\|_{\sup})$, which shows that my attempt below is somehow the only way to go.

**Attempt**: I can show the claim under the additional assumption that $1\not\in\text{supp}\, \mu$. Indeed, I may then define 
$$
\tilde{\mu}(dx):=\frac{\mu(dx)}{1-x}
$$
and proceed in two steps, using that
$$
\int_{[0,1]}(1-x^{\lambda})\tilde{\mu}(dx)=0\quad\forall \lambda>0\quad (1)
$$

1) Letting $\lambda\to\infty$, we get uniform convergence $1-x^{\lambda}\to 1$ on $\text{supp}\, \tilde{\mu}$, thus $\int \tilde{\mu}=0$.

2) Thus, Equation (1) simplifies to 
$$
\int_{[0,1]}x^\lambda\tilde{\mu}(dx)=0\quad\forall\lambda>0,
$$ 
from which we conclude $\tilde{\mu}\equiv 0$ by the Weierstrass theorem and the fact that the signed measures on $[0,1]$ are the dual space of the continuous functions.

Unfortunately, I was not able to get rid of the additional assumption. The obvious way would be to cut off $\mu$ to be supported on $[0,1-1/n]$. Equation (1) would then become
$$
\int_{[0,1]}(1-x^\lambda)\tilde{\mu}_{n}(dx)=\int_{[1-1/n,1]}\frac{1-x^{\lambda}}{1-x}\mu(dx)\quad\forall\lambda>0 
$$ 
I don't know how to proceed from here though.

Comment: how are they not? if two measures agree on those integrals, then the integrals against their difference vanish. or do you simply mean I should mentioned that? I felt the title was more succinct as is and the question was written up more succinctly as is too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\int_{[0,1]} \frac{1-x^{\lambda}}{1-x}\mu(dx)=0 \quad\forall \lambda>0$ then you have in particular $\int_{[0,1]} \sum_{k = 0}^{n}x^{k}\mu(dx)=0$ for all $n$ so that

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \, \, \int_{[0,1]}x^{n}\mu(dx)=0$$

In which case, yes the measure is uniquely determined ($\mu\equiv 0$).

In general, if the moments $(\alpha_{n}) $are finite and the series $\sum \alpha_{n}x^{n}/n!$ has a strictly positive ray of convergence then the $\mu$ is the unique measure with moments $(\alpha_{n})$

Notice, by the way that the span of $\{\frac{1-x^{n}}{1-x}: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$  is dense in $(C([0,1]),\|\cdot\|_{\sup})$